# Why this Concatenate function in ASM x64 doesn't work as desired?

Tags: c, assembly, string-concatenation

I've created the following Concat function in GAS x64 assembly, i expect it to get two pointers to two strings in rdi and in rsi, and output pointer to concatenated string of this two in rax.

```
    1 .intel_syntax noprefix
    2 .section .text
    3 .global Concat
    4 Concat:
    5     mov r8, rsp
    6     Concat_First_Loop:
    7         mov al, [rdi]
    8         test al, al
    9         jz Concat_Second_Loop
    10         push rax
    11         inc rdi
    12         jmp Concat_First_Loop
    13     Concat_Second_Loop:
    14         mov al, [rsi]
    15         test al, al
    16         jz Concat_Ret
    17         push rax
    18         inc rsi
    19         jmp Concat_Second_Loop
    20     Concat_Ret:
    21         push rax
    22         mov rsp, r8
    23         inc r8
    24         mov rax, r8
    25         ret
```

I created two pointers to strings "aa" and "bb" and tried displaying them along with concatenation of them.

```
    void Exit(int code);

    void Print_String(char* str);

    char* Concat(char* str1, char* str2);
 
    void _start() {
        char* str1 = "aa";
        char* str2 = "bb";
        Print_String(str1);
        Print_String(str2);
        Print_String(Concat(str1, str2));
        Exit(0);
    }
```

But it prints this instead:

aa
bb
��ʰU

the third being a random string of random length

Comment: You apparently tried to use the stack. At least four problems with that. 1) the memory will be freed at function return  2) you put the strings in reverse 3) you put 64 bits for each char 4) stack grows down so you even return the wrong address